# Ghostscript.Net v 1.2.1 arithmetic overflow error

Tags: c#, memory-management, out-of-memory, ghostscript.net

Has anyone seen this particular error from Ghostscript when executing the following raster.Open:

```
using (var raster = new GhostscriptRasterizer())
{
raster.Open(pdfFileStream, _version, true);
```

where _version is:

```
Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptVersionInfo _version = Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptVersionInfo.GetLastInstalledVersion(Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptLicense.GPL | Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptLicense.AFPL, Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptLicense.GPL);
```

> System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
>      at Microsoft.WinAny.Interop.DynamicNativeLibrary.FinalizeSections(MEMORY_MODULE* memory_module)
>      at Microsoft.WinAny.Interop.DynamicNativeLibrary.MemoryLoadLibrary(Byte[] data)
>      at Microsoft.WinAny.Interop.DynamicNativeLibrary..ctor(Byte[] buffer)
>      at Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptLibrary..ctor(GhostscriptVersionInfo version, Boolean fromMemory)
>      at Ghostscript.NET.Interpreter.GhostscriptInterpreter..ctor(GhostscriptVersionInfo version, Boolean fromMemory)
>      at Ghostscript.NET.Viewer.GhostscriptViewer.Open(String path, GhostscriptVersionInfo versionInfo, Boolean dllFromMemory)
>      at Ghostscript.NET.Viewer.GhostscriptViewer.Open(Stream stream, GhostscriptVersionInfo versionInfo, Boolean dllFromMemory)
>      at Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer.Open(Stream stream, GhostscriptVersionInfo versionInfo, Boolean dllFromMemory)
>      at PersonnelDocuments.Controllers.SearchController.Splitter(Stream fileStream, IEnumerable'1 adminKeys)
>      at PersonnelDocuments.Controllers.SearchController.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult'1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase'1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult'1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've got it occurring intermittently.

Comment: I ended up using a static lock and opening the library with:
raster.Open(pdfFileStream, _version, false);
as there was some issue opening from memory I believe.  So my users were okay with some periodic extra latency (if say 2 users were queued by the lock) because the nature of my website is a kind of slow-but-accurate focus on PDF uploads that inherently already take a long time.

Comment: I came across this again today. Changing `dllFromMemory` from true to false solved it for me as well. But why?